# iframe not working properly with ionic/angular js

Tags: angularjs, html, iframe, ionic-framework

I am using iframe in my ionic app to open webpages inside the application.

Here is what I have:

```
  <iframe  class= 'webPage' name= "eventsPage" ng-src="{{object.url}}"></iframe>
```

The problem is that if I use `ng-src="{{object.url}}` or `src="{{object.url}}`for getting the URL the iframe doesnt not display anything but if I put hardcoded url instead (example http://www.google.com) it just works fine.

I have also check the output of the `{{object.url}}` and it's fine, a valid url (http://www.example.com).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the $[`sce`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service in the controller and trustAsResourceUrl the url there.

```
 <iframe   ng-src="{{trustSrc(object.url)}}"></iframe>
```

and in controller

```
 $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
```